# Concatenate array elements into 32bit number

Tags: c

I'm stuck on trying to shift some hex elements into a 32bit number. I'm programming on an altera hardware board so some definition names are a little different but of course represent the same memory sizes.

Here is a basic example of what I wish to achieve starting with the code.

```
alt_u32 x = 0xC0C0C0C0;
alt_u8 y = {0xF8, 0xA0, 0xC0, 0x01};
```

I wish to change alt_u32 x so that it holds each element of alt_u8 y. So the result would look like this:

```
x = 0xF8A0C001
```

I understand that I can do this with a mask or perhaps memcpy? 
But I'm unable to explain it in code.

Cheers for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`y` should be declared as an array:

```
alt_u8 y[] = {0xF8, 0xA0, 0xC0, 0x01};
```

Then you can use bitwise operations:

```
x = (y[0] << 24) | (y[1] << 16) | (y[2] << 8) | y[3];
```

`memcpy` will work also if the architecture is `big endian`:

```
memcpy(&x, y, 4);
```

If the architecture is `little endian`, using `memcpy` the result will be `0x01C0A0F8`;

Comment: I apologize y is already an array, thank you very much for your help!